# Can OneNote display all notes sequentially in one window for quick browsing (like Evernote)?

Tags: macos, onenote

OneNote on OS X displays one note in one section of a notebook at a time. Is there a way I can get it to display all notes in a section in one big vertically scrolling window, like Evernote does?

I don't like having to click on each note in the section to view only that note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  One Note is setup much like a spiral bound notebook where you can categorize your notes, make note groups, etc.  That's is one of the differntiating features of One Note over Evernote

> User interface: OneNote looks and feels like a digital version of a
>   paper notebook, complete with tags and notebook sections. Evernote is
>   more like a filing cabinet, with a simpler notes interface yet
>   powerful tagging capabilities.

[Lifehacker - Note-Taking Showdown: Evernote vs. OneNote (2016 Edition)](http://lifehacker.com/note-taking-showdown-evernote-vs-onenote-2016-editio-1765707423)